# angularjs module and controller is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, module, controller

I'm trying to create module and controller for understanding the basic concept. I tried below code but it does not work.

```
<div ng-contoller = "MyController">
<p>
{{ author.name }}
</p>
<p>
{{ author.age }}
</p>
<p>
{{ author.sex }}
</p>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope){
    $scope.author = {
        'name'  :   'Sameer Sashittal',
        'age'   :   '28',
        'sex'   :   'Male'
    }
});
```

Above code is not working. Can any one guide me where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add you module using `ng-app` to the div.

Also there is typo error in the `ng-controller`

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller = "MyController">
```

the controller should be

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope){
```

Comment: @Karan Tiwari  nice make sure to check as answer if this helped :D

Answer (score 2):

Remove `MyController`. It should be like this.

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.author = {
      'name'  :   'Sameer Sashittal',
      'age'   :   '28',
      'sex'   :   'Male'
  }
});
```

Comment: see also @sachila ranawaka answer.

Comment: I got it their was a typo error in <div ng-contoller = "MyController">